# Gradle throw unclear message when synchronizing

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So, i just reinstalled my windows and android studio. And out of sudden, my projects cannot be synchronized with unclear message.

```
Missing ExternalProject for :
```

This is what gradle thrown at me, i've been trying to find any info about this on the internet but didn't get any result. Does it have something to do with some of my gradle was `kotlin-dsl` but some of them are groovy?